# After human life, is next step a low-level divine being?

Tags: gods, human, birth

The jiva goes from plant to insect to animal to human then divine ?

Assuming we don’t achieve moksh, and we have good karma, would the next birth after human one be a low level divine being ?

Like gandharv, yaksh, some kind of lower level celestial being in swarg lok ?

I understand it depends on karma of course but just wondering what is the next step up, after human

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> युवा स्यात्साधुयुवाऽध्यायकः । आशिष्ठो दृढिष्ठो बलिष्ठः ।
> तस्येयं पृथिवी सर्वा वित्तस्य पूर्णा स्यात् ।
> स एको मानुष आनन्दः । ते ये शतं मानुषा आनन्दाः ॥ १॥

> स एको मनुष्यगन्धर्वाणामानन्दः । श्रोत्रियस्य चाकामहतस्य । ते ये शतं मनुष्यगन्धर्वाणामानन्दाः ।
> स एको देवगन्धर्वाणामानन्दः । श्रोत्रियस्य चाकामहतस्य । ते ये शतं देवगन्धर्वाणामानन्दाः ।
> स एकः पितॄणां चिरलोकलोकानामानन्दः । श्रोत्रियस्य चाकामहतस्य ।
> ते ये शतं पितॄणां चिरलोकलोकानामानन्दाः । स एक आजानजानां देवानामानन्दः ॥ २॥

> श्रोत्रियस्य चाकामहतस्य ।
> ते ये शतं आजानजानां देवानामानन्दाः । स एकः कर्मदेवानां देवानामानन्दः ।
> ये कर्मणा देवानपियन्ति । श्रोत्रियस्य चाकामहतस्य । ते ये शतं कर्मदेवानां देवानामानन्दाः ।
> स एको देवानामानन्दः । श्रोत्रियस्य चाकामहतस्य ।
> ते ये शतं देवानामानन्दाः । स एक इन्द्रस्याऽऽनन्दः ॥ ३ ॥

> Suppose there be a youth, good, well-versed in the scriptures, well disciplined, resolute, and very strong. Suppose to him belongs all this earth full of wealth. This is one human bliss. - Taittirya Upanishad 2.8.1

> This unit of bliss of man multiplied hundred fold is the bliss of **human Gandharvas** and this is also the bliss of one, versed in the Vedas and who is free from desires. A hundred- fold of the bliss of the human-Gandharvas is the unit of measure of the bliss of the celestial Gandharvas. This is the same as the bliss of one who is well versed in the Vedas and who is free from desires. A hundred-fold of the bliss of the celestial-Gandharvas is the unit of measure of the joy of the Manes, whose world continues for long. the same is the joys expressed by one well-vesed in the vedas and who is free from desires. This joy of Manes whose worlds are relatively immortal, multiplied by a hundred-fold is one unit of trhe joy of the Ajanaja gods born in the Deva loka. And it is also the measure of the bliss of the Srotriya who has transcended all his desires. -Taittirya Upanishad 2.8.2

> This joy of the Gods born in the deva loka multipled a hundred-fold is a unit of joy of the gods (Karma Devas) who have become so by their special Karma, and it is also the joy of a Srotriya, free from desires. A hundred times this joy of the gods (Karma Devas) who have become so by their special Karma is the simple unit of joy of the gods (office-bearers) and it is also the measure of the bliss of the Srotriya who has transcended all his desires. One hundred measures of the happiness of the gods (office-bearers) is the simple unit of joy of Indra (the king of Gods) and it is also the measure of the bliss of the Srotriya who has transcended all his desires.- Taittirya Upanishad 2.8.3

Of course there's probably many creatures in middle of one Human Aananda and 100 Human Aanandas, but as a general scale, the next step is Maanushya Gandharva, then Deva Gandharva and so on.

It goes higher than Indra, but that's not very relevant to this question.

Also, you said the Jiva goes from plant to insect. There's no such rule. Even Devas can become insects, it all depends on Karma. If you're referring to it as a general scale, then never mind this paragraph.

[Source](https://shlokam.org/texts/taittiriya-2-8-1/)

Comment: Tried to upvote this but it didn’t let me, anyway, thanks for your reply !

Comment: @veganenvironmental no problem :). The upvoting requires 125 rep iirc.