# Which is second best life form after human

Tags: scripture, karma, atma, reference-request, rebirth

It is said that the human life is achieved by good deed (karma) and soul has to go through 8.4 million life forms before becoming human. So if suppose God has a point score that any soul that scores 90% and above gets the human life and if score is less than other creatures.

So my question is suppose at score of 85% some soul becomes Lion or elephant or fish or something, then what that soul becomes at just a fraction score less than 90%. i.e I want to know what is the second best life form after Human, per Hindu mythology/scriptures.

84 Life reference per [Sri Guru Gobind Singh](https://www.sikhiwiki.org/index.php/Chaurasi_Lakh_Joon_Upai,_The_8.4_Million_Lifetimes) and [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-84-lakh-yoni-in-Hindu-mythology).

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54882/in-which-scripture-it-is-written-that-there-are-84-lakh-types-of-organisms

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57688/after-human-life-is-next-step-a-low-level-divine-being

Comment: How will you measure the score for someone? *90%*, *85%*? What sort of measurement system you'll use?

Comment: @user-29449 I have no idea that is why I am asking question

Comment: You can't *measure* karma. Neither afterlife is dependent on that.  No one can prove you that.

Comment: I don't want to measure, I am not even asking how does God measure it. My question is what life form does one gets if he/she falls short of the good deed to become human.

Comment: Whatever is closest to his nature of his individuality.